# Why am I getting "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" error in shopping Cart?

Tags: reactjs, object, redux, key

I am getting an error after adding `Object.keys` and can't go through my products in my shopping cart:

[image: by adding Object. keys line I get an error and can't go through my products in my shopping cart]

**initialState:**

```
const initialState = {
  basketNumbers: 0,
  cartCost: 0,
  products: { berry: { name: 'Berries', price: 5.0, numbers: 0, inCart: false } },
}
```

Comment: const initialState = {
    basketNumbers: 0,
    cartCost: 0,
    products:{
        berry : {
            name: "Berries",
            price: 5.00,
            numbers: 0,
            inCart: false

        },

Answer (score 0):

You `Cart` component will receive `props` which will have `basketProps` property:

So, you can write:

```
funcrion Cart(props) {
  console.debug(props.basketProps)
  Object.keys(props.basketProps.products).forEach(key => {
    // ...
  })
}
```

Or with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `props`:

```
funcrion Cart({basketProps}) {
  console.debug(basketProps)
  Object.keys(basketProps.products).forEach(key => {
    // ...
  })
}
```

You are getting **error** because you are trying this:

```
funcrion Cart(props) {
  console.debug(props.products) // undefined
  Object.keys(props.products).forEach(key => { // can't convert undefined to object
    // ...
  })
}
```